# Is there a way to install v-cupertino module in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, node-modules, server-side-rendering

I've found an interesting Vue.js module called [v-cupertino](https://github.com/Devrax/v-cupertino).
But there is no solution described for implementing in Nuxt.js.

I've tried it using

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VCupertino from "v-cupertino";

Vue.component('v-cupertino', VCupertino);
```

then

```
plugins: [{src: '~/plugins/v-cupertino.js', ssr: false}]
```

but not working for me. I'm getting 10 warnings regarding somthing not found in 'vue' and Nuxt crashes.

Part of the result in Terminal:

```
 WARN  in ./node_modules/v-cupertino/dist/v-cupertino.esm.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 18:59:31

"export 'onMounted' was not found in 'vue'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    friendly-errors 18:59:31
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 18:59:31

 WARN  in ./node_modules/v-cupertino/dist/v-cupertino.esm.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 18:59:31

"export 'openBlock' was not found in 'vue'
```

Is anybody experienced using these types of modules?

Thank you,
Radek.

Comment: `ssr` does not exist anymore. Try `mode: client` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're trying to use is only for Vue3 and Nuxt currently do only support vue2. Here is the repo for Vue2.

https://github.com/Devrax/v2-cupertino

Comment: Thanks, then 

import Vue from 'vue';
import V2Cupertino from "v2-cupertino";

Vue.component('v3-cupertino', V2Cupertino);

works for me.